# Почему выходят из себя?

Tags: фразеология

Такое привычное нам выражение "выйти из себя" — разозлиться. Но, если вдуматься, почему надо при этом выходить из себя? И как это вообще — выйти из себя?

Comment: Сюда же примыкает выражение "держать себя в руках"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кстати очень точное выражение. Человеком нас делают лобные доли головного мозга, которые по большей части и определяют наше поведение, ум и вообще всё то, что делает нас человеком. При сильном эмоциональном напряжении зачастую происходит некое "возвращение к предкам", когда временно зверинные инстинкты начинают преобладать над разумом. Эти моменты действительно вполне можно описать как "вышел из себя", своей личности, человек в эти моменты словно становится другим существом, совершая такие поступки о которых в нормальном состоянии, невозможно было даже помыслить.

Comment: Человеком нас делает душа. А лобные доли делают разумным млекопитающим.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, есть у человека душа или нет - вопрос, мягко говоря спорный, а вот то, что без лобных долей головного мозга человек может существовать только на уровне растения - факт.

Comment: Душа  у  человека  конечно  есть,  она  там  и  живёт  -  в  этих  лобных  долях.

Comment: @bernard, если Вы о старом наименовании психики, то я с Вами согласен. Если же Вы имеете в виду неведомую субстанцию, которая по религиозным представлениям отделяется от человека после смерти, то вера - это дело личное, и утверждать здесь свои религиозные представления здесь явно неуместно.

Comment: Я  -  о  старом  наименовании  психики.  Эх,  не  хватает  на  нашем  форуме  смайликов - улыбнуться  невозможно !

Answer (score 3):

Попробую предложить совсем не сложное объяснение.

"А сюрпризик-то не хотите разве посмотреть?" - захихикал Порфирий, опять схватывая его немного повыше локтя и останавливая у дверей. Он, видимо, становился всё веселее и игривее, что окончательно выводило из себя Раскольникова (Достоевский).

Каждый человек  имеет определенный стереотип поведения,  который  определяется типом нервной системы, характером, приобретенными привычками.  Обычно он ведет себя так, как считает нужным, "держит себя в руках" в соответствии со своими представлениями о нормах поведения, но иногда  под воздействием какого-либо негатива  может  "сорваться",  изменить свой обычный стиль общения. Тогда получается:  "to make somebody flare up" — привести кого-то в ярость, вывести из себя.

Answer (score 0):

А где у человека располагается совесть - тоже в лобных долях?

Comment: Там же. Вся высшая нервная деятельность там происходит.

Answer (score 0):

После того. как человек уйдёт в себя, надо же ему потом из себя выйти:)))

Comment: Конечно,  надо.  Но  эти  два  похожих  выражения  не  являются  антонимами  по  смыслу.  Они  входят  в  разные  синонимические  ряды.  Сначала  ушёл  в  себя,  а  потом  возвратился  к  своим  друзьям  и  близким.

Answer (score 0):

Это очень интересный и глубокий вопрос! Мне близок ответ Софии. Ведь действительно, человек - это созданный в течение жизни стереотип, которым он управляет. Этот стереотип - это программа, частично заложенная генетически, частично созданная обществом, частично - самим индивидом. Возможно, эта программа и находится в лобных долях, как утверждает уважаемый Яzz, и человек постоянно контролирует её. Но здесь следует задуматься: Кто контролирует? Кто держит себя в руках? Кто выходит из себя?  Выходя из себя, человек теряет этот контроль вплоть до того, что не помнит, что происходило в тот момент, когда он был не в себе.  Отрицая существование души, можно считать себя образованным человеком, т. е. стереотипом, созданным из образов, как правило, чужих мыслей.  Но духовным  человеком, вправе считать себя лишь тот, кто стремиться постичь себя и свою душу, соединиться с ней, а не отвергать. Тогда не будет никаких «выходов из себя», ведь Человек станет собой, а не образованным стереотипом.

Answer (score 0):

Душа, дух выходит из тела. Отсюда "выйти из себя" - преобразиться до неузнаваемости, потерять первоначальный облик, подменить свою сущность. Ведь если мы из себя выходим, что-то демоническое в нас входит, потому что свято место пусто не бывает.

Answer (score 0):

Когда ЧЕЛОВЕК в себе,его не совсем "видно" ,т.е. не знаешь ,на что он способен,опасен или нет и т д.... А вот когда он "ВЫШЕЛ ИЗ СЕБЯ",тут то и видно всю его суть. Толи он будет топотить ногами и рвать на себе волосы,толи возьмёт дубинку и огреет хорошенько.Сразу видно кто есть кто! По этому и говорят "держи себя в руках" ,скорее людям,которым есть что показать.

Answer (score 0):

Между прочим, выражение "выйти из себя" нужно понимать буквально. Человек выходит из себя, когда сознание выходит из его тела. Под сознанием можно понимать душу, эфирное тело. Это происходит, когда человек нервничает, устаёт морально и физически.